# have been + V ing vs have been + V ed

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I know that Present Perfect Progressive is have been + ing.
I've been learning since 9 o'clock;

But which tense is `have been V + ed` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the passive form of present perfect.